# Можно ли при сохранении файла с помощью casperjs указать кодировку?

Tags: парсер, phantomjs, casperjs

Есть ли в casperjs возможность указывать кодировку при сохранении в файл html-содержимого страницы? У меня сохраняется в ANSI, а нужно utf-8

```
casper.thenOpen(myurli, function(){

   var page1 = this.getHTML();
   fs.write(file_path, page1, 'wb');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ага, только смотреть нужно не во fs.write а в fs.open.

```
var myFile = fs.open('/path/to/file', {
    mode: 'w',
    charset: 'UTF-8'
});
```

[phantomjs - open()](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/open.html)